# AWS Cloudformation Quick create link doesn't provide additional options

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am using quick create to deploy CFT in AWS and using this feature there is no options of configuring execution role and other options.

I want to use role to deploy CFT when people click on Quick Link.

Answer (score 0):

This is because "Quick create" is meant to provide a simplified workflow for when you don't need to provide additional configuration. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-console-create-stacks-quick-create-links.html):

> This simplifies the process of creating stacks by reducing the number of wizard pages and the amount of user input that's required.

If you want to have access to all options, simply use the full creation flow. On the stacks page, click "Create stack". From there, you can provide the template URL and configure all the available options.